# Not getting the parameter from the URL in Express

Tags: express, routes

I am having a hard time pulling the id from the URL in Express. I keep getting {} as the id when I use req.params.id. The request is routed through 3 different files: server.js, getListingRoutes.js and getListing.js. Here is what the code looks like:

server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500
const { logger, logEvents } = require('./middleware/logger')
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/errorHandler')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = require('./config/corsOptions')
const connectDB = require('./config/dbConn')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

app.use(logger)
connectDB()
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use('/listings/:id', require('./routes/getListingRoutes'))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
app.use('/', require('./routes/root'))
app.use('/listings', require('./routes/getAllListingsRoutes')) // Working
app.use('/new-listing', require('./routes/createNewListingRoutes')) // Working
app.use('/edit-listing/:id', require('./routes/updateListingRoutes'))
// app.get('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
//     console.log(req.params.id)
// }) // Getting the params here.
app.use('/listings/:id/add-view', require('./routes/addViewToListingRoutes'))
app.use('/listings/user/:userId', require('./routes/getUserListingsRoutes'))
app.use('/my-listings', require('./routes/getUserListingsRoutes'))

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404)
    if (req.accepts('html'))
    {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', '404.html'))
    }
    else if (req.accepts('json'))
    {
        res.json({ message: '404 Not Found'})
    }
    else
    {
        res.type('txt').send('404 Not Found')
    }
})

app.use(errorHandler)
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err)
    logEvents(`${err.no}: ${err.code}\t${err.syscall}\t${err.hostname}`, 'mongoErrLog.log')
})
```

getListingRoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const getListingController = require('../controllers/getListing')

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id, "@", Date.now());
    next();
});


router.route("/")
    .get(getListingController.getListingRoute)

module.exports = router
```

getListing.js:

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const path = require('path')

// @desc GET specific listing
// @route GET /listings/:id
// @access Public
const getListingRoute = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Reached getListing.js")
    const id = req.params.id
    console.log(req.path)
    if (!id)
    {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Listing ID required' })
    }

    const listing = await User.findById(id).exec()

    if (!listing)
    {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Listing not found!' })
    }
    console.log(listing)
    res.json(listing)
})

module.exports = {getListingRoute}
```

server.js calls getListingRoutes.js and it calls getListing.js which does the actual work. I think the problem is the router.route('/') line in the getListingRoutes.js file since I feel like I should be passing the id there somehow but if I put in anything aside from "/" there the call to getListing.js is never made.

This is the request I send using Postman: "http://localhost:3500/listings/a7609764-646d-48bd-8b60-fc5d0c83c4e8"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

I have tried putting in different parameters for the router.route('/') line but call to the getListing.js is not made if I put in anything aside from "/" in it.

Comment: Feels weird to have the `:id` param in the `app.use()`. Could you try `app.use("/listings", require('./routes/getListingRoutes'))` and `router.get("/:id", getListingController.getListingRoute)`?

Comment: I did try that but got a 404 error in Postman. getListingRoutes.js did not call getListing.js after using "router.route("/:id").get(getListingController.getListingRoute)" because I don't see the console.log("Reached getListing.js") log in the terminal.



I also put in the following code in the getListingRoutes.js:
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id, "@", Date.now());
    next();
});

The req.params.id gives undefined here. So the req is not even reaching getListingRoutes.js

Comment: Try moving the `app.use("/listings...` above the other routes and `static`. Routes should ideally be registered in most-to-least specific order. Could be something in `routes/root` is also handling the requested URL

Comment: I tried moving the app.use('/listings/:id', getListingRoutes) line and commenting out the static and routes/root lines but I am still not getting the req.params.id in the getListingRoutes.js file.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question so it matches your current code?

Comment: Also, why are you logging `req.path`? I would think if you wanted to log anything, it would be `req.params.id`

Comment: I was just testing to check if the path reached the file. Just for testing purposes. Had req.params.id before

Comment: _"I have uploaded all the code to Github"_... that's not how it works here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit] your question

Comment: Ah I see. I have updated the server.js and getListingRoutes.js file. In the getListingRoutes.js file the console.log(req.params.id, "@", Date.now()); gives undefined. The logger file simply logs the request in a log file and console.log the path of the request to the terminal. Already tried commenting out the logger call in server.js but it still does not work

Comment: I think I found the solution. When I call const router = express.Router() in the getListingRoutes.js it sets the params to {}. Apparently, this is how the express.Router file works but if I put in const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true }) it does not set the params to {}. Had to use the debugger to catch that line in the express.Router file.